# I Want when I decrease product quantity to 0 product not remove from cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i Have A Woo-commerce Site And I Am Using Ajax For Update Cart Item And Total When I Click +/- in Work Nice But When i decrease product quantity to 0 And Than Try To increase product quantity it will Not Update And When I decrease product quantity to 0 Then Refresh The Page Product Remove From My Cart

I Just Want To When I decrease product quantity to 0 Cart Get Product Price is O And Then I increase product quantity 0 to whatever Cart Will Update With New Total

Plz Go To Demo Link And See What I Want [Demo](http://woocommerce-ajax-cart.trickwordpress.in/13-2/)

See The [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIfHs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The item is removed from the cart by the [`WC_Cart->set_quantity()`](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#1017) method when the new `$quantity` provided is 0.

There is an action called just before the item is removed, so it might be possible to hook to that action and re-add the item, but it seems kludgy at best.

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_item_quantity_zero', $cart_item_key );
```